# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Double to String

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, type-conversion

my Blog class is here

```
package com.nego.lakshan.nego;


public class Blog {

private String FROM;
private String TO;
private String DESCRIPTION;
private String IMAGE;
private String DATE;
private double TOLAT;
private double TOLNG;
private double FROMLAT;
private double FROMLNG;

public Blog(){

}

public Blog(String FROM, String TO, String DESCRIPTION, String IMAGE, String DATE, String TOLAT, String TOLNG, String FROMLAT, String FROMLNG) {
    this.FROM = FROM;
    this.TO = TO;
    this.DESCRIPTION = DESCRIPTION;
    this.IMAGE = IMAGE;
    this.DATE = DATE;
    this.TOLAT = Double.parseDouble(TOLAT);
    this.TOLNG = Double.parseDouble(TOLNG);
    this.FROMLAT = Double.parseDouble(FROMLAT);
    this.FROMLNG = Double.parseDouble(FROMLNG);
}



public String getFROM() {
    return FROM;
}

public void setFROM(String FROM) {
    this.FROM = FROM;
}

public String getTO() {
    return TO;
}

public void setTO(String TO) {
    this.TO = TO;
}

public String getIMAGE() {
    return IMAGE;
}

public void setIMAGE(String IMAGE) {
    this.IMAGE = IMAGE;
}

public String getDATE() {
    return DATE;
}

public void setDATE(String DATE) {
    this.DATE = DATE;
}

public double getTOLAT() {
    return TOLAT;
}

public void setTOLAT(String TOLAT) {
    this.TOLAT = Double.parseDouble(TOLAT);
}

public double getTOLNG() {
    return TOLNG;
}

public void setTOLNG(String TOLNG) {
    this.TOLNG = Double.parseDouble(TOLNG);
}

public double getFROMLAT() {
    return FROMLAT;
}

public void setFROMLAT(String FROMLAT) {
    this.FROMLAT = Double.parseDouble(FROMLAT);
}

public double getFROMLNG() {
    return FROMLNG;
}

public void setFROMLNG(String FROMLNG) {
    this.FROMLNG = Double.parseDouble(FROMLNG);
}


public String getDESCRIPTION() {
    return DESCRIPTION;
}

public void setDESCRIPTION(String DESCRIPTION) {
    this.DESCRIPTION = DESCRIPTION;
}

}
```

and my Fragment class is use to view the data in recycler view which i get from the  runtime database (Firebase).
and my fragment class is here

```
package com.nego.lakshan.nego;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;




public class RecieverFragment extends Fragment {


public RecieverFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

private RecyclerView mBlogList;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
private View v;

@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reciever, container, false);


    mBlogList= (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment);


    mBlogList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");





    mBlogList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));



    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"mmmm",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return v;





}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog,BlogViewHolder> 
 mFirebaseRecyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>
(Blog.class,
            R.layout.blog_item,
            BlogViewHolder.class,
            mDatabaseReference) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Blog 
 model, int position) {


            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"maaa",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            viewHolder.setDATE(model.getDATE());
            viewHolder.setDESCRIPTION(model.getDESCRIPTION());
            viewHolder.setFROM(model.getFROM());
            viewHolder.setTO(model.getTO());




        }
    };
    mBlogList.setAdapter(mFirebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}

public static class BlogViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    View mView;

    public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView=itemView;}
    public void setDATE(String DATE){
        TextView date = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.DATE);
        date.setText(DATE);
    }

    public void setDESCRIPTION(String DESCRIPTION){
        TextView desc= (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.DESCRIPTION);
        desc.setText(DESCRIPTION);
    }

    public void setFROM(String FROM){
        TextView from = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.FROM);
        from.setText(FROM);
    }

    public void setTO(String TO){
        TextView to = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.TO);
        to.setText(TO);
    }

    }
}
```

and my fragment layout File

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.nego.lakshan.nego.RecieverFragment"
android:id="@+id/place_holder">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</FrameLayout>
```

and im using CardView for  view (blog posts)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="20dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="104dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="1">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/PROFILEPIC"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.05" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="244dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/NAME"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="53dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/DATE"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="52dp" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/DESCRIPTION"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="164dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.16"
            android:weightSum="1">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="From"
                android:layout_weight="0.31" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:text="To"
                android:layout_weight="0.51" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.88"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/FROM"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.41" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TO"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.19" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="109dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="FROMLOCATION"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TOLOCATION"/>


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="164dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="DIrection"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Message"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and im getting error and the app crashes when i call the fragment

```
com.nego.lakshan.nego E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: 
com.nego.lakshan.nego, PID: 28426

com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of 
type java.lang.Double to String
                                                                       at 
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaD(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at 
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at 
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at 
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at 
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zze(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at 
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaG(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at 
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zze(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at 
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at 
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at 
com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at 



com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.parseSnapshot(FirebaseRecycler
Adapter.java:163)
                                                                       at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:152)
                                                                       at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:195)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6356)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6389)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5335)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5598)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5440)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5436)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2224)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1551)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1511)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3583)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3312)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1648)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:343)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:549)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
```

please, help me on this.

Comment: add your database please

Comment: @Lakshan Chamika You need to convert double value to string while inserting the records. just use this (""+yourdouble value) while inserting the record this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was added some values to test and I forgot to remove them from the firebase realtime database.. And later i realized and deleted them then it worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your Blog.class. While you are declaring the following variables as double, your class constructor is accepting Strings to initialize it:

```
private double TOLAT;
private double TOLNG;
private double FROMLAT;
private double FROMLNG;
```

now the problem is that Firebase Database is going to save it as per the definition here and in the 'get' methods i.e. as Double. But when they are retrieving the blogs, from the database for the class constructor it is failing to convert it to String.

Please fix your variable types to consistent declarations and this error should go away.